# Are there rules for cost of robot armor?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg, umerica

In the *Umerican Survival Guide*, under "Robot Weapon Training" (p. 77), it says:

> Given a proper facility and materials, Robots can convert, construct,
> and repair proper robo-armor that does not inflict the extra Fumble
> penalty.

Are there rules for the cost of this?

I do see in the armor section ("Common Armor Pieces and Sets" - p. 119) it says:

> Impervious or other special armor, per die step = 50+3d10sp

However to me, this infers the cost of normal Impervious armor and the above quote infers Robot is more.  If you believe this inference is wrong, I welcome that as an answer for other people to vote on.

I intend to ask my GM, so am really looking for citations or quotes I missed, vs "my group does..." or "I would...".

(I understand there's a new release of the guide either coming out or recently released.  Mine says Copyright 2017.  I don't see how to tell what edition it is otherwise – but am happy to provide that information with guidance.)